# sftp using expect to automate file transfer not working

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sftp

I want automate below command so as to pass the password and proceed with file transfer.

```
#This command works well but it will require password
echo "put This_file_from_server_a.csv /TO/THIS/SERVER_B/PATH" | sftp remote@10.11.12.13
```

i have tried to use `expect`, so as to automate/ send password automatically, but it is not working i.e.

```
expect -c 'spawn "put This_file_from_server_a.csv /TO/THIS/SERVER_B/PATH" | sftp remote@10.11.12.13; expect "assword:"; send "THE_PASSWORD\r"; interact'
```

I get error

> send: spawn id exp4 not open
>       while executing "send "THE_PASSWORD\r""

What could be the issue? without considering alternatives: such as `sshpass`, `lftp`, `private keys`...

Comment: What is that ppl try to use `expect` with `sftp` - why? `What could be the issue?` - you are `spawn`-int command `put` - there is no such command. I guess you are missing `echo` in front of `put`.

Comment: @KamilCuk No it doesn't , the server i am using i have restricted rights. it doesn't have SSHPASS and lftp `sshpass: command not found`  `lftp: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating private keys on both servers that you are trying to do the transaction then try doing the same, it should work

in case it does not use expect as below.

```
expect  <<'END_EXPECT'
set timeout -1
spawn sftp remote@10.11.12.13
expect "assword:"
send "THE_PASSWORD\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put This_file_from_server_a.csv /TO/THIS/SERVER_B/PATH\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
END_EXPECT
```